# GCM 3'rd party server API key and registration Id

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm investgating GCM push issue.

In my scenario, i want to send push message to multiple apps.
For example i have a App A,B,C
I want to send push to App A,B,C

As i know to send push from 3'rd party server to client, it needs APIKey and registration key. (Is that all?)

To send the push to different client. Do i have to use different API Key or same API key?
Let's assume that developer account for App A,B,C are different

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the Credentials section in the [Key Concept](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#key) of GCM overview page.

If you have only one 3rd party server, but multiple client applications, you will need one sender ID for your 3rd party server, one API key for your 3rd party server to access the Google services, and multiple application IDs for your client applications.

Also to note that the registration ID is tied to a particular Android application running on a particular device.